# Brasero is not writing discs

Tags: burning, brasero

When I use Brasero to write disks, it seems the recording occurs flawless, but, the disk is unreadable.

Xfburn is working well, but Brasero not. I would like to use Brasero, but it makes me waste disks.

Has someone seen this before?

Comment: Is there anybody else here facing problems with Brasero or it's just me?

Comment: Hi. I've the same problem. I lost two DVDs and I don't understand what is occurring.

Answer (score 3):

I've got it.

I had the same problem as MidnightHunter burning cd's. Try to disable the first option at the burning menu; something like **Burn disk image directly without saving it**
(My software is in Spanish, so maybe these aren't the correct words)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a known bug - just don't check the "burn on the fly" option. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/780117

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install the plugin dvdauthor from the Ubuntu Software Center for your dvd to work. I hope this is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Dvdauthor is installed and Brasero keeps not recording as it would do.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem with DVD-RWs. Sometimes Brasero creates readable disks and sometimes (although the write completes successfully) it creates coasters (ok, a bit carried away: RWs are in fact reusable).

I've written a script as a workaround to burn a directory of files to DVD-RW. It combines genisoimage and wodim.